# Limit the number of single processes in Nextflow workflows

Tags: workflow, nextflow

I have the following simple workflow:

```
workflow {

  Channel.fromPath(params.file_list)
        .splitText(){it.trim()}
        .set { file_list }

  data = GetFromHPSS(file_list)
  data_pairs = CoupleDETXToFile(data, file(params.detx_path))
  SingleDUTimeResFit(data_pairs)

}
```

In which `file_list` is a list of paths on a tape-drive system. The `GetFromHPSS` is the process which retrieves files from the tape system and I need to limit the parallel processes to a fairly low number.

Currently, I am using

```
executor {
  queueSize = 100
}
```

in the configuration file but there are two problems:

1. it limits the overall maximum number of parallel jobs, while I could run thousands of `SingleDUTimeResFit` processes in parallel
2. it always first waits until it processed everything from `GetFromHPSS` instead of continuing with the subsequent processes

Here is an example:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `workflows/singledu_timeresfit.nf` [wise_galileo] - revision: 8084ac1482
executor >  sge (502)
[13/ca3e8a] process > GetFromHPSS (426)  [ 18%] 402 of 22840
[-        ] process > CoupleDETXToFile   [  0%] 0 of 402
[-        ] process > SingleDUTimeResFit -
```

Is there a way to limit `GetFromHPSS` to a specific number of parallel executions and let the remaining processes run with another queue-limit set?

EDIT: This is one of my best tries I guess, but it does not accept the configuration:

```
process {
  executor {
    queueSize = 100
    submitRateLimit = "10sec"
  }

  withName: GetFromHPSS {
    executor.queueSize = 10
  }
}
```

With this `process` top-level configuration, I get:

```
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 21.04.3
Launching `workflows/singledu_timeresfit.nf` [confident_pasteur] - revision: 8084ac1482
Unknown config attribute `process.withName:GetFromHPSS` -- check config file: /sps/km3net/users/tgal/dev/PhD/workflows/nextflow.config
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you're looking for here is the [maxForks](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#maxforks) directive, which can be applied to just the 'GetFromHPSS' process without the need to change the executor's queueSize:

```
process 'GetFromHPSS' {

    maxForks 1

    """
    <your script here>
    """
}
```

You could even parameterize it, if you think it makes sense:

```
params.hpss_forks = 5

process 'GetFromHPSS' {

    maxForks params.hpss_forks

    """
    <your script here>
    """
}
```